# What is meaning of X(1,:) = [x y]; in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am not a matlab user,I just want to rewrite a function from matlab to python.
So my question is excatly like in tittle,what is meaning of X(1,:) = [x y];
When X is array and x,y are vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose:

```
x = [1 2 3]
y = [4 5 6]
```

Then `[x y]` results in

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

So the two vectors are concatenated.

`X(1,:) = ...` assigns the right hand side to the first row of matrix `X`.

Answer (score 0):

`X(1,:) =` means "put whatever's on the right into the 1st row of `X`".

`[x y]` means horizontal concatenation.

Note that if `X` exists in the workspace, the combination of `x` and `y` needs to be of the correct size, or else you'll get a `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` error.

You can see an example in the answer of [m.s.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684553/3372061)